# Django Model Boolean Field needs to be initially unchecked. initial=False required=False is not working

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-forms

**Forms.py**

```
class CheckPostedForm(forms.ModelForm):
        posted = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False)
```

**Views.py**

```
       postform = CheckPostedForm(request.POST, instance=author)
       if postform.is_valid():
            postform.save()
       else:
            print 'Cannot save post form.'
```

**Models.py**

```
posted = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
class Meta:
    model = TmpPlInvoice
    exclude = ['net_amt', 'post_date', 'address', 'particulars', 'pos_code', 'acct', 'cust', 'voucher_id', 'voucher_date', 'post_date']
    labels = {
        'posted': 'Posted',
    }
```

I want a checkbox which is initially unchecked and based on th value from DB i check/uncheck it. No matter what i do the form always comes out as checked="checked".

print postform gives this,

```
<tr><th><label for="id_posted">Posted:</label></th><td><input checked="checked" id="id_posted" name="posted" type="checkbox" value="n" required /></td></tr>
```

I have searched alot every where, the docs say that it should be initially false required=False if we want to apply conditions.

**Detail**
**Views.py**

```
def master_detail_posted(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        author = TmpPlInvoice.objects.get(id=1)
        postform = CheckPostedForm(instance=author)
        return render(request,'main.html' ,{'postform': postform})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        author = TmpPlInvoice.objects.get(id=1)
        postform = CheckPostedForm(request.POST, instance=author)
        print postform
        if postform.is_valid():
            logger.info('saving post form %s', postform.cleaned_data)
            postform.save()
        else:
            logger.info('post form is not valid %s %s', postform.errors, request.POST)
        return render(request,'main.html' ,{'postform': postform})
```

**Template**

```
<div> {{ postform }} </div>
```

Comment: how about using a wiget.. `posted = forms.BooleanField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput())`

Comment: anyway, whereis your `class Meta: <enter> model = ModelName` inside `CheckPostedForm`?

Comment: @SancaKembang Still the same result.

Comment: please update your complete code...

Comment: @SancaKembang Please review.

Answer (score 0):

You've hard coded the field in the template. Clearly, Django can't change HTML tags that you've written explicitly.

You need to use Django tags in your template:

```
<td>{{ form.posted }}</td>
```

Comment: I have pasted the html for clarity.This is what Django generates dynamically. I am using Django tags in template.

Comment: Then you need to show your actual template, and the *full* view.

Comment: Your forms and models are all mixed up (eg the Meta that you've posted on the model looks like it's actually from the form). Please post the actual full definitions for both - plus the rest of the view, showing for example where `author` comes from.

Comment: @RNA solved problem?